# Passing variables to javascript in imagebutton onclientclick in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, query-string

I want to pass my dynamic value received in querystring to a javascript function from an imagebutton onclientclick event :

```
    Request.QueryString["id"].ToString()

    <asp:ImageButton ID="btn" runat="server" 
        OnClick="btn_Click"
        ImageUrl="/images/events.gif" 
        OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure delete the id number XXXXXX ?');" />
```

I need that on XXXXX is the value passed in querystring.

I have tried without success of the examples found on google.

Can you help me ?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: You could always do it via code-behind if you wanted to validate the query string.  Obviously you don't want to display that message if the ````id```` is an empty string.  Granted, you might already have validation on Page_Load.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `<% %>` to grab the ID from the query string:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btn" runat="server" 
    OnClick="btn_Click"
    ImageUrl="/images/events.gif" 
    OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure delete the id number <%# Request.QueryString["id"].ToString() %> ?');" />
```

Comment: Thank you I have error *Parser Error The server tag is not well formed*

Comment: Try swapping the double quotes for `OnClientClick` with single quotes. Like: `OnClientClick='return confirm...;'`